# OnPrem DevOps Agent returning System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path '/agent/_work/1/s/$HOME/.config/NuGet/nuget.config' error

Tags: azure-devops

We have Azure DevOps onPrem Linux agent and pipeline that interact with bitbucket.

This is the sequence of event:

1st time pipeline run and fail on a powershell task (e.g. exit 1)

2nd time pipeline run, the agent start return the following error when trying to checkout bitbucket resource:

"System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path '/agent/_work/1/s/$HOME/.config/NuGet/nuget.config' is denied"

That agent now corrupt and no longer usable.

This does not happen when I use azure agents.

Any advice on what is going wrong or how to analyse this issue?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> "System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path '/agent/_work/1/s/$HOME/.config/NuGet/nuget.config' is denied"

Based on the error message, the cause of the issue can be that the account used to run the Azure DevOps Self-hosted Linux Agent doesn't have enough permission to access to the target path.

Refer to the following steps:

1.Check the account used to run the Azure DevOps Agent. You can navigate to **Pipeline log -> Initialize Job** and find the account.

[image]

2.You can run the following command on the target linux machine to grant the user the read and write permissions to the `/agent/_work` folder.

For example:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /agent/_work
```

Or

```
sudo chown -R localaccountname /agent/_work
sudo chmod -R u+rX /agent/_work
```

**Update:**

To solve this issue, we need to re-configure the Pipeline agent and enable the root access to all the directory in azure devops.

Here are the steps:

Step1: Download the the agent Zip file and unzip it.

Step2: Open config.sh and run.sh file. Add the following script:

```
export AGENT_ALLOW_RUNASROOT="1"
```

For example:

Config.sh

```
user_id="$(id -u)"
export AGENT_ALLOW_RUNASROOT="1"
# we want to snapshot the environment of the config user
if [ $user_id -eq 0 -a -z "$AGENT_ALLOW_RUNASROOT" ]; then
    echo "Must not run with sudo"
    exit 1
fi
....
```

Run.sh

```
...
export AGENT_ALLOW_RUNASROOT="1"
# Validate not sudo
user_id=`id -u`

if [ $user_id -eq 0 -a -z "$AGENT_ALLOW_RUNASROOT" ]; then
    echo "Must not run interactively with sudo"
    exit 1
fi
...
```

Step3: Run `sudo ./config.sh` and `sudo ./run.sh` to config and run the new agent again.

For more detailed steps, you can refer to this blog: [System.UnauthorizedAccessException:Azure Devops CI/CD Pipeline Permission Issue- Fix](https://sandipdulal.medium.com/system-unauthorizedaccessexception-azure-devops-ci-cd-pipeline-permission-issue-fix-033bfaf4bb8c)

Comment: That would not fix the issue as the azure devops pipeline agent rerun will just fail again.

Comment: I've extend the original comment with screenshot of the error log

Comment: Check the screenshot shared by you. Can you confirm if the issue exists when checkout the repo in pipeline?

Comment: issue exist in the 'Checkout step', have added screenshot above

Comment: @user7786267 Check the updated steps in the answer and try to re-config the agent again. Feel free to let me know if it can work.

Comment: I'll look at the solution and come back to confirm whether it work.  I'm afraid I don't have access to our agents, will either get someone else to do it or wait for access.

Comment: Will wait for your feedback

Comment: @user7786267 Is there any update for the latest status now? Feel free to let me know if the method can work for you